# How to loop audio playlist?

Tags: loops, audio, playlist

I really love this pen https://codepen.io/himalayasingh/pen/QZKqOX and have been having lots of fun tinkering around with this audio player, but I can't for the life of me seem to get it to loop through the playlist properly. after every track the audio stops, I've been able to get the selected track to loop but not loop through the entire playlist. any insight?

```js
$(function()
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl, albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'), sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'), sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, tFlag = false, albums = ['Dawn','Me & You','Electro Boy','Home','Proxy (Original Mix)'], trackNames = ['Skylike - Dawn','Alex Skrindo - Me & You','Kaaze - Electro Boy','Jordan Schor - Home','Martin Garrix - Proxy'], albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5'], trackUrl = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/2.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/1.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/3.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/4.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/5.mp3'], playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;

    function playPause()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if(audio.paused)
            {
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
                checkBuffering();
                i.attr('class','fas fa-pause');
                audio.play();
            }
            else
            {
                playerTrack.removeClass('active');
                albumArt.removeClass('active');
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fas fa-play');
                audio.pause();
            }
        },300);
    }

     
 function showHover(event)
 {
  seekBarPos = sArea.offset(); 
  seekT = event.clientX - seekBarPos.left;
  seekLoc = audio.duration * (seekT / sArea.outerWidth());
  
  sHover.width(seekT);
  
  cM = seekLoc / 60;
  
  ctMinutes = Math.floor(cM);
  ctSeconds = Math.floor(seekLoc - ctMinutes * 60);
  
  if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
   return;
  
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
   return;
  
  if(ctMinutes < 10)
   ctMinutes = '0'+ctMinutes;
  if(ctSeconds < 10)
   ctSeconds = '0'+ctSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(ctMinutes) || isNaN(ctSeconds) )
            insTime.text('--:--');
        else
      insTime.text(ctMinutes+':'+ctSeconds);
            
  insTime.css({'left':seekT,'margin-left':'-21px'}).fadeIn(0);
  
 }

    function hideHover()
 {
        sHover.width(0);
        insTime.text('00:00').css({'left':'0px','margin-left':'0px'}).fadeOut(0);  
    }
    
    function playFromClickedPos()
    {
        audio.currentTime = seekLoc;
  seekBar.width(seekT);
  hideHover();
    }

    function updateCurrTime()
 {
        nTime = new Date();
        nTime = nTime.getTime();

        if( !tFlag )
        {
            tFlag = true;
            trackTime.addClass('active');
        }

  curMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
  curSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMinutes * 60);
  
  durMinutes = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
  durSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMinutes * 60);
  
  playProgress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
  
  if(curMinutes < 10)
   curMinutes = '0'+curMinutes;
  if(curSeconds < 10)
   curSeconds = '0'+curSeconds;
  
  if(durMinutes < 10)
   durMinutes = '0'+durMinutes;
  if(durSeconds < 10)
   durSeconds = '0'+durSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) )
            tProgress.text('00:00');
        else
      tProgress.text(curMinutes+':'+curSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            tTime.text('00:00');
        else
      tTime.text(durMinutes+':'+durSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) || isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
        else
            trackTime.addClass('active');

        
  seekBar.width(playProgress+'%');
  
  if( playProgress == 100 )
  {
   i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
   seekBar.width(0);
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            albumArt.removeClass('buffering').removeClass('active');
            clearInterval(buffInterval);
  }
    }
    
    function checkBuffering()
    {
        clearInterval(buffInterval);
        buffInterval = setInterval(function()
        { 
            if( (nTime == 0) || (bTime - nTime) > 1000  )
                albumArt.addClass('buffering');
            else
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');

            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

        },100);
    }

    function selectTrack(flag)
    {
        if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
            ++currIndex;
        else
            --currIndex;

        if( (currIndex > -1) && (currIndex < albumArtworks.length) )
        {
            if( flag == 0 )
                i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            else
            {
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fa fa-pause');
            }

            seekBar.width(0);
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            tTime.text('00:00');

            currAlbum = albums[currIndex];
            currTrackName = trackNames[currIndex];
            currArtwork = albumArtworks[currIndex];

            audio.src = trackUrl[currIndex];
            
            nTime = 0;
            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

            if(flag != 0)
            {
                audio.play();
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
            
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                checkBuffering();
            }

            albumName.text(currAlbum);
            trackName.text(currTrackName);
            albumArt.find('img.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#'+currArtwork).addClass('active');
            
            bgArtworkUrl = $('#'+currArtwork).attr('src');

            bgArtwork.css({'background-image':'url('+bgArtworkUrl+')'});
        }
        else
        {
            if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
                --currIndex;
            else
                ++currIndex;
        }
    }

    function initPlayer()
 { 
        audio = new Audio();

  selectTrack(0);
  
  audio.loop = false;
  
  playPauseButton.on('click',playPause);
  
  sArea.mousemove(function(event){ showHover(event); });
  
        sArea.mouseout(hideHover);
        
        sArea.on('click',playFromClickedPos);
  
        $(audio).on('timeupdate',updateCurrTime);

        playPreviousTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(-1);} );
        playNextTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(1);});
 }
    
 initPlayer();
});
```